# Regular expression to match style="whatever:0; morestuff:1; otherstuff:3"

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match anything between and including `style=""`
eg: `style="whatever:0; morestuff:1; otherstuff:3"`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The pattern will be `/style="([^"]*)"/`, but may vary a bit depending on what language you're using.

Also if you're trying to do this through javascript, jquery would make this as easy as

```
$("#element-id").attr("style");
```

If you're trying to do this from another language, use an HTML parsing lib as HTML isn't regular. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for Python is quite nice.

Comment: That will work, until you have `<div style="some stuff here" id="this-div">`, you will end up matching `some stuff here" id="this-div`, since .* is greedy.  You want to use the character class `[^"]`, that is match everything **besides** a double quote.

Comment: In Notepad++, use  `style="([^"]*)"` (mind the double quotes and mind the leading space).

Answer (score 6):

**String under test**

```
style="whatever:0; morestuff:1; otherstuff:3"
```

**Regex**

```
style\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"
```

**Contents of group 1**

```
whatever:0; morestuff:1; otherstuff:3
```

### Notice!

It is very hard to write a regex-based HTML parser that is correct, secure, and maintainable.  If you need to write program that deals with HTML in a robust, reliable, and secure way, you should use a real HTML parsing library like jsoup (Java) or Html Agility Pack (C#).  To find an HTML parser for your favorite language, Google: `yourlanguage html parser`.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to remove all style tags from html (clean inline styles entirely), use this as regexp:

```
style=\"[^\"]*\"
```

This works for me in sublime text 2-3

Answer (score 2):

```
/(style="([^"]*)")/
```

for the whole string (untested). do you want the key value pairs retrieved as well?